# Add a "times" block helper to Ember application

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to add a block helper to my application, which does the following. In my template I want to be able to write

```
{{#times n}}
<p>Some text</p>
{{/times}}
```

which should return the code included inside the block n times (n should be a variable from the template's model). For example when n is 3 in the template's model, the output should be

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
```

I read that specifying block helpers in Ember is not possible (yet). Is there some kind of workaround for my problem?

Kind regards,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

I think (untested) this is what you need:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('times', function(context, options) {
    var result = "";

    for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
      result = result + options.fn(this);
    }

     return result;
});
```

Read through this:
http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Comment: As of RC7, Ember doesn't support custom block helpers. They may have changed that in RC8 or 1.0, but it seems like a rather large change for a small release.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution would be a computed property in the controller...

```
times: function(){
 var timesArray = [];
 for(var i = 0, l = this.get('model.n'); i < l; i++){
  timesArray[i]=i;
 }
  return timesArray;
}.property('model.n')
```

And use a normal each helper

```
{{#each controller.times}}
    <p>Some text</p>
{{/each}
```